# How to Leverage Browser Caching using .htaccess ? (Google Maps api)

Tags: .htaccess, google-maps, caching

So I have tested my page via Googles Page Insights 
And it is currently telling me to:

> Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
>   http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en (30
>   minutes)

Its rather ironic as its a google resource from a google server But 
Its always good to know how to do things I've tried to read about how to do this on a link google provided on the test page however it didn't really give an example of how to cache this external resource I've tried reading as much as I can and adding bits into my htaccess file but nothing seems to work.

So I guess my question firstly is, is it even possible via the .htaccess file to cache this resouce?
And if so how what code would I need to put in there to get it to cache the resource?

Thanks you In advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't control the caching of resources served from third party. htaccess is to control caching for resources served out of your own boxes.

Comment: I suppose hosting the js on my own server and manually updating the files when they start to break would be the only option then.

Comment: Which is what precisely some people do. OR you could trust a third party like Google enough to say that they know what they are doing ... that low expiration of 30 minutes is by design .... that "wait for break then fix" might mean that you are forever doing that every 30 minutes. There is no right answer,